# Grouping multi values in one variable

Tags: batch

I have serveral departments in my company. I need to use different Windows keys to activate its Windows. How can I group the departments into one variable using one key, the others using another keys so my batch script can be much easier.

```
REM ComputerName Group
HR-16
DD-89
CC-05
AB-50
XY-23
LM-46
NO-15
RB-09
CF-05

set group1=HR-16  DD-89  CC-05
set group2=CF-05  RB-09  NO-15
set group3=AB-50  XY-23  LM-46

set key1=AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE
set key2=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.11111
set key3=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.22222


if %computername:~0,5%==%group1% if %computername:~-2%==-X (
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %key1% 
) else (
if %computername:~0,5%==%group2% if %computername:~-2%==-X (
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %key2% 
) else (
if %computername:~0,5%==%group3% if %computername:~-2%==-X (
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %key3% 
)
)
)
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato

@exit /b
```

[image]

[image]

Combined two options into one batch file

```
@echo off

REM Windows Activation
echo ================================
echo Choices:
echo. [1] = Input Key
echo. [2] = Pre-Set Key
echo ================================

goto choice


:choice
Echo ComputerName : %computername%
Choice /n /c 12 /m "Activation Choice : "%1
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto input
If "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto preset


:input
echo %errorlevel%

Echo Activate Windows
echo. =================================
set /p key="Input Windows KEY : "
echo. =================================

echo. %key%
echo. Press ENTER to continue if correct
pause
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %key%
ping /n 3 localhost>nul 2>&1
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs  /ato
ping /n 3 localhost>nul 2>&1
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr
ping /n 3 localhost>nul 2>&1
goto end



:preset

set group1=HR-16,DD-89,CC-05
set key1=AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE
call :ActivateWindows "%group1%" %key1%

set group2=CF-05,RB-09,DS-60
set key2=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.11111
call :ActivateWindows "%group2%" %key2%

set group3=AB-50,XY-23,LM-46
set key3=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.22222
call :ActivateWindows "%group3%" %key3%

cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato

endlocal
exit /b %errorlevel%

:ActivateWindows [group] [key]
for %%G in (%~1) do for %%K in (%~2) do (
    if "%computername:~0,5%"=="%%G" if "%computername:~-2%"=="-X" (
        echo Activating Group: %%G and Key: %%K
        cscript //nologo %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %%K
    )
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: Any help or advise ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set group1=HR-16,DD-89,CC-05
set key1=AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE
call :ActivateWindows %group1% %key1%

set group2=CF-05,RB-09,NO-15
set key2=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.11111
call :ActivateWindows %group2% %key2%

set group3=AB-50,XY-23,LM-46
set key3=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.22222
call :ActivateWindows %group3% %key3%

cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato

endlocal
exit /b %errorlevel%

:ActivateWindows [group] [key]
for %%G in (%~1) do for %%K in (%~2) do (
    if "%computername:~0,5%"=="%%G" if "%computername:~-2%"=="-X" (
        echo Activating Group: %%G and Key: %%K
        cscript //nologo %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %%K
    )
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: Will try and let you know the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: your code does not work on group with more than one computername. If there is two computernames, it will treat the second computername in that group as Windows Key. If the group has more than two computernames, it does not work.
Also I want to add a criteria that if the computername does not fall in any group, a error message will pop up.    echo This Computer is out of range and not able to activate
       ping /n 10 localhost>nul 2>&1

Comment: Really want to know if there is a way to simplify the code ?

Comment: Hi, with the help of others. Put quotes for the group strings make your code works. However is it possible to combine your code with another input choice in one batch file. I put the combined code together as shown but only the input part works. Any advice how to fix the preset script to run ?